# How to properly authenticate access to localhost in the same network?

Tags: apache, authentication

I have an apache server running on my local machine. I can connect to `http://localhost` from a different device in the same network, but I want to add a layer of authentication. So that when the user tries to access the localhost, it has to enter the correct username/pwd to proceed. Is there anyway to do this without having it the authentication code in the javascript or html file returned by the apache server? I'm new to this so I'm a little confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure apache to require authentication. Have a look at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/auth.html